# Application.Current is null in Release mode

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF app with some debug and release code preprocessing. NoteList is a UserControl. This control don't have any preprocessor directives, therefore, should work just fine. In the Debug mode it's working, but in release mode `Application.Current` is throwing `NullReferenceExeption`.

```
public partial class NoteList : UserControl
{
   public NoteList()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Loaded += (sender, e) =>
       {
           UpdateItemSourse();              
       };
   }

   private void UpdateItemSourse()
   {
       var app = Application.Current; //exception is here
       //another stuff
   }
}
```

visual studio debugging tools shows that Application.Current is not null

[image: visual studio debugging tools shows that Application.Current is not null]

I'm confused. What could be wrong?

Comment: The usual entrypoint for a wpf app is main. That generates an application object that becomes application.current.  That application also has thread affinity. So.... Non standard entry point, usercontrol library in winforms app or different thread to main. Any of those the case?

Comment: Nope, just regular WPF usercontrol in the same project.

Comment: Entry point is autogenerated. I used OnStartup event of the App class to process command prompt args and manually set Current.MainWindow. I've deleted StartupUri form App.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in one of the ViewModel classes. One of the fields was null that must be not null. I fixed that and it started to work. I can't even imagine how it's linked with the App object and NullReferenceException in here.